# why address of variable is different to what is returned by pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, function-pointers, memory-address

i am using this manipulate function to get the pointers address but it returns anything else.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int *manipulate( int &b) {
    int *a=&b;
    cout<<&a<<" "<<&b<<" ";     // why memory add of 'a' and 'b' different ?
    return a;         // is it returing pointer which stores address of 'b' ?
}

int main() {
    int x=44;
    cout<<&x<<" "; // gives memory address of x;
    int *ptr=&x;
    cout<<ptr<<" "; //  gives mem address of x;
    int &l=x;
    cout<<&l<<" "; //  gives memory add of x;
    int *c=manipulate(x);  //storing returned pointer
    cout<<&c;  // why address of 'c' different to that of returned pointer?
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in manipulate function you receive `&b` by reference.

in this line:

```
int *a=&b;
```

you have defined a **pointer variable a with value of b address**

in this line:

```
cout<<&a<<" "<<&b<<" ";
```

you have printed **the address of a (the pointer)** and **address of b**

if you want them the same you could:

```
cout<<a<<" "<<&b<<" ";
```

and finally you have returned the **a** (pointer to b)

but in your main

```
int *c=manipulate(x);
```

you have created a pointer name c with value of address of x

if you want to print the address of x you could:

```
cout<<c;
```

Comment: if m answer solved your problem you can accept it using "tick"